# What is the difference between & and * in C++ function arguments?

Tags: c++, syntax

As an example I know that

```
void foo(int *num)
{
num++;
}
```

```
foo(&num);
```

will pass `num` by reference. However, why do people use

```
void foo(int &num)
{
num++;
}
```

I've heard that you should use that syntax over what I posted above, why is this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57492/12243443

Comment: `int *num` does not pass `num` by reference.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Did you meant `void foo(int *num)
{
(*num)++;
}`?

Comment: `int *num`, `foo(&num);` This passes a pointer to `num` by value.

Comment: "*Pass-by-reference*" *might* refer to "*pass-by-pointer*" in the context of C, but in C++ these are certainly different things, see linked duplicate.

Comment: It's the same reason people use both hammers and screwdrivers. They do different things, and each one has its own use cases where the other one isn't convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example passes by pointer, *not* reference.

The second example `void foo(int &num)` is a function that takes its argument by reference.